# Can't make regex pattern for 8 and 13 digits in middle of string work

Tags: c#, .net, regex

EDIT 2:

Yes like I thought, i need to change the pattern to 2 different ones, because the OR will make a match for 13 digits a match for 8 digits one

```
THE SOLUTION IS:
Regex EAN8 = new Regex(@"\b\d{8}\b");
Regex EAN13 = new Regex(@"\d{13}\b");
```

PS FOR EDIT2: As someone said, problaly in the future i will end up finding EAN1234567890123 or EAN_1234567890123, these patterns wont work out, and I have no idea where to start searching for a pattern like this.

I'm doing a project where I need to take multiple EANs from a text.
I already have a validation class to see if they are valid or not.
And I can take the 13 digits one (but I think the pattern I'm using is not correct and will give problems sooner or later.

Example of a string: "OL‐120 112 82 Estuchado, fácil apertura. 8410032002279 227 24"

as you can see there is a valid EAN13 in the middle: "8410032002279"
I'm using this pattern:

```
Regex EAN13 = new Regex(@"\d{13}");
```

It gives me the EAN inside the string, but I think the correct pattern should be like this:

```
Regex EAN13 = new Regex(@"\d{13}$");
```

But when I use it it doesn't work. probably because the string doesn't end there.

I have a similar problem with the EAN of 8 digits, if i use this pattern:

```
Regex EAN8 = new Regex(@"\d{8}");
```

It gives me the 13 digit eans cut to 8...

What should I do to make both patterns work whatever the position of the EAN is in the string and for the 8 digit return only a real string with 8 digits and not one with more cut down to 8.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Further Code to understand what I'm doing

```
Regex EAN = new Regex(@"\b(?:\d{8}|\d{13})\b");
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"....txt"))
        {
            string currentLine;
            while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Match m13 = EAN.Match(currentLine);
                Match m8 = EAN.Match(currentLine);

                if (m8.Success)
                {
                    lista_EAN8.Add(m8.Value);
                    //string valido8 = new Ean8Validate().ValidateEan8(m8.Value);
                    //if (valido8 == m8.Value)
                    //{
                    //    lista_EAN8.Add(m8.Value);
                    //} 
                }

                if (m13.Success)
                {
                    string valido13 = new Ean13Validate().ValidateEan13(m13.Value);
                    if (valido13 == m13.Value)
                    {
                        lista_EAN13.Add(m13.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Like this it returns me the same values in list of 13 digit eans and list of 8 digits eans

Comment: i think you mean this `\b(?:\d{8}|\d{13})\b`

Comment: because when I tried to add the $ to EAN8 pattern it didn't match me any result (as it should) but could actually be since the string didn't end there it didn't match.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number_(EAN)

Comment: that pattern returns me eans with 13 digits where I'm looking 8

Comment: Which 8 digits you want? Post the expected output for the above input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok looks like you want 2 different Regexs one for targeting only 8 digit matches and the other for targeting 13 digit matches

for matching of the 8 digit EANs use;

```
\b(?:\d{8})\b
```

for matching and for 13 digit EANs use;

```
\b(?:\d{13})\b
```

additionally is you want an options prefix of EAN(upper or lowercase) you can use;

for 8 digit

```
\b(?:[Ee][Aa][Nn])?(?:\d{8})\b
```

for 13 digit

```
\b(?:[Ee][Aa][Nn])?(?:\d{8})\b
```

for your example you want to modify the code so it read something like this.

```
Regex EAN8 = new Regex(@"\b(?:\d{8})\b");
Regex EAN13 = new Regex(@"\b(?:\d{13})\b");
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"....txt"))
    {
        string currentLine;
        while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Match m13 = EAN13.Match(currentLine);
            Match m8 = EAN8.Match(currentLine);

            if (m8.Success)
            {
                lista_EAN8.Add(m8.Value);
            }

            if (m13.Success)
            {
                lista_EAN13.Add(m13.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

now if we tweek the Regexs a little more we can extract just the number parts out of EAN numbers even when they are prefixed with EAN* or EAN_*

```
Regex EAN8 = new Regex(@"\b(?:[Ee][Aa][Nn]_?)?(\d{8})\b");
Regex EAN13 = new Regex(@"\b(?:[Ee][Aa][Nn]_?)?(\d{13})\b");
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"....txt"))
    {
        string currentLine;
        while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Match m13 = EAN13.Match(currentLine);
            Match m8 = EAN8.Match(currentLine);

            if (m8.Success)
            {
                lista_EAN8.Add(m8.Groups[1].Value);
            }

            if (m13.Success)
            {
                lista_EAN13.Add(m13.Groups[1].Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

this will capture the number part while throwing away the EAN prefix

Comment: Well you almost answered my 2nd doubt on edit of main post.
Where I ask how can I make a pattern for EAN1234567890123 or EAN_
I think the 2nd possibility is really low or next to none but I need to account for even a minimal possibility

Comment: I've added a modified version of your example to match the current simple use case. (just a string of 13/8 digits)

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make the pattern for the special case with EAN_

`\b(?:[Ee][Aa][Nn])?(?:\d{13}| [Ee][Aa][Nn][_])?(?:\d{13})\b`

Answer (score 1):

Use the below regex to match `8` or `13` digits. `\b` is a word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character. So it avoids matching 8 digit number in a 13 digit number.

```
\b(?:\d{8}|\d{13})\b
```

Comment: this one shows me ean's with 13 digits in the 8 digit list

Comment: what's your actual input and the expected output?

Comment: See edit on main post please

This is happening probably because I'm using everything together in the same pattern, and they should be separated, one for the 8 digits, and another one for 13 digits.

Since it has a OR in the pattern, it finds the match for 13 digits and returns it

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex string.  `\b` = word boundary and the `|` makes sure that it will only match 8 or 13 and not some number in between:

`\b\d{8}\b|\b\d{13}\b`

Comment: This will never match EAN in something like `EAN3145345435566`. But unfortunately there is such EAN-writing on some product labels and websites.

Comment: @rufanov Correct.  Going by the example, I'm assuming (maybe incorrectly) that isn't the case.

Comment: same as previous examples, ean's with 13 digits return as match for 8 digits

Comment: @Jorge, Not with the word boundary characters, it doesn't.  `1234567890123` will match `1234567890123` and not `12345678` or any other combination.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean that.
I mean that the it returns match success for ean of 13 digits.
In this pdf to string I dont have lines with 8 digit ean's.
Only 13, and the match for 8 digits eans is returning values with 13 digits

I edited the main post with rest of code

Answer (score 0):

If you want dob't allow unicode digit use character class instead shortcut \d ( it's much faster)

```
\b(?:[0-9]{8}|[0-9]{13})\b
```

Comment: same as previous, I can't use this to search for 8 digits ean's, it returns me 13 digit ones as a match

Answer (score 0):

I managed to concoct this:

```cs
\b(([Ee][Aa][Nn])?[_]?([0-9]{13}|[0-9]{8}))\b
```

1. This part `([Ee][Aa][Nn])?` groups the case-insensitive sequence EAN and makes it optional with `?`

   2. Then `[_]?` makes the underscore optional. I added the square brackets for prettiness sake
   3. The digits are identified using their character representation `[0-9]{13}` and `[0-9]{8}`
   4. Everything is wrapped up in a `\b( ... )\b` block to identify the word boundary
   5. The two EAN types are wrapped by parentheses and separated by an OR `|`

Below is a screenshot from http://regexpal.com/ showing the testing set and the matching.

[image: Screenshot from regexpal.com showing the testing set and the matching.]

Jorge, I must say I don't like repeating code, (or anything else for that matter :D ). I am therefore not very fond of the whole `([Ee][Aa][Nn])?[_]?` appearing twice. Moreover if tomorrow you wish to look for EAN5 for example you must further copy it and the regexp becomes ever more ugly.

---

Here is what I had before the cleanup:

```cs
\b(([Ee][Aa][Nn])?[_]?[0-9]{13}|([Ee][Aa][Nn])?[_]?[0-9]{8})\b
```

Below is a screenshot from http://regexpal.com/ showing the testing set and the matching.

[image: Screenshot from regexpal.com showing the testing set and the matching.]